# How can I apply classes to images based on their aspect ratio with PHP?

Tags: php, css, drupal-6

I'm working on a drupal6 site and I've got a page that shows thumbnail images (linked to full node content).

The images are currently allowed to have a dynamic width based on the parent div, and are both vertical and horizontal.

the problem I'm having is that there is a max-width applied to these images, which crushes my horizontal images.
the question I have is: how can I use PHP to get the image element which has a unique ID, discover if it is horizontal or vertical and apply a CSS class based on the image's aspects.

I'd need to either put this in my template.php as a pre-process, or in my page.tlp.php.
I can't use Jquery/javascript because I can't risk the FOUC. I also and developing this site as a multi-site drupal instal per instructions, and I'm not allowed to have anything outside my own site directory folder.

I've looked at getimagesize() and getElementsByTagName() but I'm just not sure how to put it together as my PHP is pretty limited. I'm hoping that someone here can point me in the right direction VS giving my the answer.

Thanks
Stephanie

Answer (score 1):

Basically use [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to extract the width and the height of the image. Then compare the two. If width is bigger than height, print `image-horizontal`, else print `image-vertical`. Here is a sample code that will do the job. It uses `list` to get just the first two elements of the returned by `getimagesize` array which are the widht and the height. Then inside the `echo` statement, we do the check and print the appropriate class:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($your_full_path_to_image);
echo '<img src="'.$your_url_to_image.'" class="'.(($width > $height) ? 'image-horizontal' : 'image-vertical').'" />';
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have just one question - do i put this in the head of the doc? or as an addition/replacement of the IMG tag?

Comment: You should put it as a replacement of the IMG tag.

Comment: I've added your code to my test and I'm not sure where  to declare the two variables of $your_full_path_to_image and $your_url_to_image - I've tried to add my images which are in the same folder as the test code and only get a return of "horizontal".  i've changed the code look like this 'code'<?php list($width, $height) = getimagesize("horizontal.jpg");
echo "<img src=\"horizontal.jpg\" class=\"'.($width > $height) ? 'image-horizontal' : 'image-vertical'.'\"/>";
?>'code'  it returns the source view of <img src="horizontal.jpg" class="'.(480 > 300) ? 'image-horizontal' : 'image-vertical'.'"/>

Comment: Sorry, my bet. I forgot to place a () around the triple operator. I will modify the code

Comment: Thanks that helps - but now I'm seeing a blue or red border with no image (I'm doing something wrong with the VARs), any ideas?

<?php
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('horizontal.jpg');
echo '<img src=\"horizontal.jpg\" class="'.(($width > $height) ? 'image-horizontal' : 'image-vertical').'" />';
?>

 I’ll also have to figure out how to get the image elements by ID since I can’t replace my image tags.

I appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: Check in the HTML what is the `src` of the image and what should be the correct path.

Comment: the images are in the same folder as the page, here is the line of my alt image - <img src="vertical.jpg" id="grid" />

Comment: Is this coming from the browser's source? What was the URL of the image before? On what URL the browser returns 404?

Comment: HI All, Thanks for the help, I ended up finding and using a very generic plugin that defined a height and width - since I had to apply by class. it doesn't serve my needs the way I really need it to, but it was good as a patch. Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up, I'm sorry to say I never got this working in the way I'd laid out in my original question.
I'm not sure if it wasn't possible, not possible in my specific instance, or if I was simply unable to figure it out.

I ended up using straight css to do the scaling and faked a consistant width by adding backgrounds